# WebStorm and Next.js (TypeScript) suggestions/validation issues

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, next.js, webstorm

I have problem with my WebStorm (2023.03). The IDE does not recognize any TypeScript validation or suggestion.

- Sometimes it shows errors, but it last only a few seconds.
- When I try to build project bunch of errors appear which I don't see in the IDE.
- Sometimes my code just white, without any color.
- Sometimes I see that my IDE eats too much resources.

Maybe there is some sort of fix or something to make WebStorm work with next.js + TypeScript?

- Project uses TypeScript 5.3.3 and node 21.2.
- I'm using MacBook Pro M2 Pro 32GB RAM
- The IDE automatically detected `eslintrc` and `prettierrc`.
- There are checkmarks on "Show project errors" and "Show suggestions"

P.S. Everything works well on simple React projects.

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".next",
    "dist",
  ]
}
```

**prettierrc.json:**

```json
{
  "printWidth": 140,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "semi": true,
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "bracketSpacing": true
}
```

**eslintrc.json**

```json
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@next/next/recommended",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "no-useless-return": "error",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off",
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,
    "no-console": "warn",
    "react/display-name": "off",
    "no-extra-boolean-cast": "warn",
    "no-use-before-define": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": "error",
    "no-unsafe-optional-chaining": "off",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "off",
    "react/no-array-index-key": "warn",
    "prefer-const": 1,
    "object-shorthand": "warn",
    "newline-before-return": "warn",
    "newline-after-var": [
      "warn",
      "always"
    ],
    "no-trailing-spaces": "error",
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
      "error",
      {
        "max": 1
      }
    ],
    "prefer-arrow-callback": "warn",
    "arrow-body-style": [
      "warn",
      "as-needed"
    ],
    "no-unused-vars": ["warn", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["warn", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }],
    "react/jsx-curly-brace-presence": "error",
    "prefer-template": "error",
    "curly": "error",
    "quotes": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "warn",
      "single"
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  }
}
```

I already tried to delete `.idea` folder and re-create the project. Tried to disable/enable eslintrc. Tried ChatGPT to look through my configs, nothing...

Comment: What errors aren't reported - the ESlint or typescript compiler ones? I'd suggest creating a ticket in youtrack, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB, so that we can investigate the issue